# Save singleton object to disk - native Iphone app

Tags: iphone, object, save, nscoding, encoder

I'm having some troubles trying to save a singleton object to the iPhone disk.

The object is a collection of 2 arrays, which contain the faved posts and faced jobs.
Basically -->   `Favorites = arrayOfFavedPosts + arrayOfFavedJobs`

Now I am trying to save the `Favorites` object, so that the once faved posts or jobs can be read from the disk.

[my Faves.m file](http://pastebin.com/FJJuDgXv).

Error:

```
2012-04-26 14:56:56.957 FirstDesign_test2[666:10403] -[Post encodeWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c74a80
```

This error fires up when I call the `saveToDisk` method when I add a new object to one of the arrays...

Some help would be really appreciated!

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adopt and implement the `NSCoding` protocol on your `Post` class (and presumably on your `Job` class).

[*NSCoding Protocol Reference*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)
[*Archives and Serializations Programming Guide: Encoding and Decoding Objects*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Archiving/Articles/codingobjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000948-BCIHBJDE)